# Infer type arguments recursively

Tags: typescript

I want to recursively infer type arguments in an interface.

The basic structure is this:

```js
{
    value: 'abc',
    fn: (value) => { /* ... */ },
    children: [
        {
            value: 123,
            fn: (value) => { /* ... */ }
        },
        {
            value: false,
            fn: (value) => { /* ... */ }
        }
    ]
}
```

It is possible to indefinitely nest these inside one another using the `children` property. The type of the `value` property is always the same as that of the adjacent `value` parameter of `fn`. This, in theory works like this:

```js
interface Foo<T> {
    value: T,
    fn: (value: T) => void,
    children: Foo<???>[]
}
```

My issue is that I do not know what type parameter to pass down to the `children` type. Passing down `T` does not work, because then all the types would be the same.

Also please note that the solution must work with inference. The objects need to be constructed using a simple inference helper function like this:

```js
function makeFoo<T>(foo: Foo<T>): Foo<T> {
    return foo;
}

const foo = makeFoo({
    value: 'abc',
    fn: (value) => { /* ... */ },
    children: [
        {
            value: 123,
            fn: (value) => { /* .... */ }
        },
        {
            value: false,
            fn: (value) => { /* .... */ }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I sincerely doubt it's possible to get this kind of contextual inference to happen recursively.  Are you interested in refactoring to a different approach to represent the same information?  Or do you just want a "no" answer (with sources to the basic thing preventing it, mostly [ms/TS#74599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599))?

Comment: I think it's possible to do this in the shape of `makeFoo<T>(foo:T): Foo<T>`. And return `never` if it is invalid, though I'm not sure if this fits you. If it does I can attempt to do that

Comment: @jcalz If it is not at all possible then I am of course open to alternatives. I was thinking about using classes where each child is added individually. This would reduce the scope of the generic type parameters.

Comment: If you're willing to *call* `makeFoo()` recursively, then you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLX1Zm) or like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO1j6m).  Does that meet your needs (assuming wonderflame doesn't come up with something better)?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?